# Return rownumber in R for first value with a whole hour in it

Tags: r

For an analysis I'm running I want to know the first row in my dataset where the column "time" is a whole hour. So for instance I have:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("14:56:00","14:57:00","14:58:00","14:59:00","15:00:00","15:01:00"))
```

I want to find the rownumber where x is a whole hour, which would be 15:00:00 in this case.

Now even better would be if it only returns the first case where this happens, but I think I can figure a way to work around this. I though maybe *grepl* was a way, but I don't think that works very well with time functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `grep`

```
grep(":00:00", df$x)[1]
#[1] 5
```

---

Or convert to Date Time class and then do the evaluation

```
v1 <- strptime(df$x, "%H:%M:%S")
which.max(v1$sec==0 & v1 $min == 0)
#[1] 5
```

Comment: +1 for the second option.  `grep` looks to be about 150 times slower than using the `POSIXlt` object.  If you are using a `POSIXct` object, using `which(as.numeric(x) %% 3600 == 0)` gives comparable results (though I'm sure there is some idiosyncrasy I'm not considering).

Comment: @Benjamin I was also trying something using `times` from `chron` and `3600` though couldn't get it right. Thanks

Comment: If I understand `times` objects correctly, their numeric representation is the proportion of 24 hours since 00:00:00.  To use a times object, I believe `which(as.numeric(x) %% (1/24) == 0)` would be the correct approach.

Comment: Also with `lubridate`, `which.max(minute(x) == 0 & second(x) == 0)`

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment.  I got way too curious with this, and timed all of the various options discussed.  And good news!  There's an efficient way to do this when you're using `POSIXlt`, `POSIXct`, or `times` objects.

```
library(chron)
library(microbenchmark)
library(lubridate)

x <- c("14:56:00",
        "14:57:00",
        "14:58:00",
        "14:59:00",
        "15:00:00",
        "15:01:00")

x <- x[sample(seq_along(x), 10000, replace = TRUE)]

x_times <- times(x)
x_lt <- strptime(x, "%H:%M:%S")
x_ct <- as.POSIXct(x, format = "%H:%M:%S")

microbenchmark(
  grep = grep(":00:00", x),
  substr = which(substr(x, 3, 8) == ":00:00"),
  posixlt = which(x_lt$min == 0 & x_lt$sec == 0),
  posixct = which(as.numeric(x_ct) %% 3600 == 0),
  chron_times = which(as.numeric(x_times) %% (1/24) == 0),
  lubridate_lt = which(minute(x_lt) == 0 & second(x_lt) == 0),
  lubridate_ct = which(minute(x_ct) == 0 & second(x_ct) == 0)
)
Unit: microseconds
         expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
         grep 1874.412 1882.4765 1900.3438 1887.9015 1897.8715  2090.239   100  b 
       substr  737.508  743.9590  780.8664  745.7180  748.3570  1843.328   100 a  
      posixlt  266.851  270.0780  295.3843  272.4230  275.0630  1436.600   100 a  
      posixct  244.272  248.0840  268.9425  249.5500  252.3365  1365.341   100 a  
  chron_times  244.272  249.4040  269.2798  251.7495  256.7345  1078.257   100 a  
 lubridate_lt  286.206  290.6045  315.7149  294.8565  300.5750  1415.487   100 a  
 lubridate_ct 3100.169 3128.1750 4017.1479 3166.1495 4038.4020 50903.542   100   c
```

### Including variable coercion times

```
microbenchmark(
  grep = grep(":00:00", x),
  substr = which(substr(x, 3, 8) == ":00:00"),
  posixlt = {
    x_lt <- strptime(x, "%H:%M:%S")
    which(x_lt$min == 0 & x_lt$sec == 0)
  },
  posixct = {
    x_ct <- as.POSIXct(x, format = "%H:%M:%S")
    which(as.numeric(x_ct) %% 3600 == 0)
  },
  chron_times = {
    x_times <- times(x)
    which(as.numeric(x_times) %% (1/24) == 0)
  },
  lubridate_lt = {
    x_lt <- strptime(x, "%H:%M:%S")
    which(minute(x_lt) == 0 & second(x_lt) == 0)
  },
  lubridate_ct = {
    x_ct <- as.POSIXct(x, format = "%H:%M:%S")
    which(minute(x_ct) == 0 & second(x_ct) == 0)
  }
)

Unit: microseconds
         expr        min         lq        mean     median          uq        max neval   cld
         grep   1877.931   1894.353   1908.4255   1898.604   1905.2030   2109.300   100 a    
       substr    739.853    748.651    796.1005    750.704    754.0755   2083.788   100 a    
      posixlt  64857.238  65131.127  66115.4777  65293.731  66145.3095 113194.606   100   c  
      posixct 127864.696 128861.283 130728.4082 129356.279 130059.3290 191846.601   100    d 
  chron_times   8319.317   9237.315  10899.4629   9526.746   9779.0825  59084.740   100  b   
 lubridate_lt  64874.832  65149.895  65733.2789  65315.431  65820.5420  79871.888   100   c  
 lubridate_ct 131143.743 132104.263 133843.4980 132782.388 133162.1380 182147.867   100     e
```

Comment: benchmarks added.  I'm not sure this would change my approach, however--primarily because I'm prone to make my variables be whatever type I want them to be for the analysis, and then choose a method for deal with that type.  But the difference in approach would be inconsequential in static data sets.  In something more dynamic and fluid, it could have a larger impact.

Comment: Wow, thanks Benjamin. It's an analysis I have to repeat 280 times in a loop, so the speed aspect actually is very applicable.